# Why do I get Unidentified Index: username and password?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

Update: It appears I've made a successful AJAX POST request as it outputs the PHP errors in #userError and have change of the errors in my old code, but I still get the Unidentified Index

At this point, I have tried literally everything I can think of...

My question: Why am I getting unidentified Index for both username and password on checkLogin.php, when on login.php the information is not an invalid index.

- I've tried switching $_POST['username'] (&pwd) to $_REQUEST, hoping that my work but it doesn't

This is the function that is called so long as both username and password input fields are filled in. I use event.preventDefault(); to block the submit, which is called after the page fully loads, and the function is called if error == 0.

```
function checkLogin() {

    $("#login_form").submit(function(event) { //Create a Submit Handler

            //var formData = ; //Serialize the form data

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //Launch XML Request
                http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    $(this).text(this);
                    $("#userError").text(this.responseText);
                }
            };

            http.open("POST", "checkLogin.php", true);
            http.send();
    });

    $("#login_form").submit(); //Submit the form
```

checkLogin.php (DB is a placeholder for the actual private info)

```
    $link = mysqli_connect('DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'); //Database Connection

    if (!$link) { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { //Keeps the text inside the this.responseText
        //Preparing and Binding SQL statement
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username =? and password =?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $password);

        //PRINTS UNIDENTIFIED INDEX
        $username = $_POST['username']; //mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']); //Retrieving the username 
        $password = $_POST['password']; //mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']); //Retrieving the password
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
    }

if (!$stmt) {
echo "this is invalid";
}
```

HTML Form Tag: (no form content included here -- but it's there on the client_login.php)

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form">
</form>
```

Expected: If the info is incorrect, do nothing (right now) -- If correct, run login.php script 
Actual: Unidentified Index for $username and $password

Error: Notice: Undefined index: username in (filePath)/checkLogin.php on line 15

 Notice: Undefined index: password in (filePath)/checkLogin.php on line 16

Comment: Try `$("#login_form").serialize()` instead.

Comment: It didn't change anything, I think ```var $form = $(this)
        var post = $.post("checkLogin.php", $form.serialize());``` did the same thing

Comment: Why are you submitting the form twice in `checkLogin()`?

Comment: It seems you may be applying your responseText to a userError element upon receiving a response with a status code of 200, which signifies a successful transaction. You need to invert this with an exclamation point:


if (this.readyState == 4 && !this.status == 200) {

    $("#userError").text(this.responseText);

}

Comment: You are already performing an AJAX POST request to `checkLogin.php` with `$.post()`. Why are you then performing another one with no data via `xmlhttp.send()`?

Comment: _" I use event.preventDefault(); to block the submit"_  where? It's not in your code. Also, where do you call `checkLogin()`?

Comment: @Jeemusu I wasn't aware I was, I assumed that one handled the submit (but didnt submit it) and then the second instance actually submits the form

Comment: @Phil I didn't know they both performed the AJAX POST request, is there one you would suggest removing? --- the code with the event.preventDefault(); and calling the function are below, called after the page fully loads, I omitted it to save space, all that occurs is an error check against username and password fields to see if their empty, if not, it calls the function

Comment: I highly recommend you familiarise yourself with the functions you're using in your code ~ https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/.

Comment: Dont use the escaping. That will have unexpected results with the parameterized query. Also hash your passwords if you aren't.

Comment: @user3783243 I'll take a look into hashing my passwords as soon as I get this part finished, and I removed the escaping, thank you